# JavaScript default parameters for function

Tags: javascript, parameters, ecmascript-6, default

I can fully understand ECMAScript 6 has created a lot of potential way of handling with functions such as arrow functions.

Since I'm not very familiar with the new stuff, when talking about default parameters for a function. How to interpret the differences between the following way of defining functions:

Function 1:

```
function m1({x = 0, y = 0} = {}) {
  return [x, y];
}
```

Function 2:

```
function m2({x, y} = { x: 0, y: 0 }) {
  return [x, y];
}
```

Comment: I think with javascript you can do it with another approach.
it would be something like function m1(x) { x || (x=0); }

Comment: @lsqleakey  are you asking how to create an arrow function with default vars in ES6?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is clear when you try passing something  to your functions:

```
m1({}) // [0, 0]
m1({z: 1}) // [0, 0]
m1({x: 1}) // [1, 0]

m2({}) // [undefined, undefined]
m2({z: 1}) // [undefined, undefined]
m2({x: 1}) // [1, undefined]
```

Your first syntax (`m1({x = 0, y = 0} = {})`) does three things:

- First, it provides a default first argument to the function, which is an empty object. If no first argument is given (`m1()`) then the default empty object is used (i.e. it becomes `m1({})`)
- Second, your code extracts the `x` and `y` properties from that object.
- If either is `undefined`, it is given a default value `0`.

`m2({x, y} = { x: 0, y: 0 })` does something quite different:

- First it provides a default first parameter to the function, which is the object `{x: 0, y: 0}`. If no first argument is passed, that object is used. If any argument other than `undefined` is passed, that value is used instead.
- Second, the code extracts the `x` and `y` properties from that object. If they are `undefined`, that's what you'll get.

The first option (a parameter with a default value that is destructured with more default values) is almost certainly what you want. The second option means that your code does not have sensible/useful default values for the property if arguments are passed.

Comment: `m2()` will produce `[0,0]`. `m2({})` would be `[undefined, undefined]`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Thanks: that is of course what I meant.

Comment: Assumed so, great explanation, nice breakdown

Answer (score 0):

`m1` provides default values for `x` and `y`, whereas `m2` merely destructures `x` and `y` from a provided object and only provides default values if the object itself isn’t provided:

- `m1({})` will return `[0, 0]`
- `m2({})` will return `[undefined, undefined]`
- Both `m1()` and `m2()` will return `[0, 0]`

---

- `m1({x: 10})` will return `[10, 0]`
- `m2({x: 10})` will return `[10, undefined]`

So, if `m2` receives an object, it will destructure the available values to the variables `x` and `y`. If any of them is missing, it’s `undefined`. Only if the whole object is missing, it’ll provide a default object (`{ x: 0, y: 0 }`) from which to get the values.

`m1`, however, provides default values for both properties even if they’re missing. And if the whole object is missing, it’ll still provide those default values.