# Default argument value of a function, destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments, destructuring

Guys, some theory work here.

There's a function -

```
function lol( { x = 10 } = {}, { y } = { y : 10 } ) {
console.log( x, y )
};
```

Things are getting hairy here

```
lol(); // 10, 10
lol( {}, {} ); // 10, undefined
```

1. Why am i getting `undefined` after passing empty object?
2. And why am i getting default value of `10` for `y` when lol() ?

I am lost, need help!

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42093572/417562).

Comment: Indeed, gotta search more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
(function ({x = 10}) {
  console.log(x)
})()
```

There would be a TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'
and if you try:

```
(function ({x} = {}) {
  console.log(x)
})()
```

Now, this gives `undefined`.

---

This follows:

```
function({x} = {}) { ... }
```

`x` is matched with `undefined`, as **no property on right-hand-side of assignment has the property `x`**.

```
function({x = 10} = {}) {...}
```

Again, `x` gets matched with `undefined` so, it takes the default value of `10`.

---

On the other hand, your second argument (taken separately)

```
function({ y } = { y : 10 }) {...}
```

here, the match happens and `y` gets the value as `10`
but when you pass an empty object, the default argument object `{y : 10}` gets overridden.

which is equivalent of having:

```
function({ y } = {}) {...}
```

Here, you don't have anything to match y with, so it gets set to `undefined`

Comment: Wow, thank you, Amresh! Now i have reached a 100% on this very topic. Very rich explanation.

Comment: :) Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass nothing for `y` you get the default value of `{ y : 10 }` hence `y` is 10.

When you pass an empty object JS tries to get the `y` property because of `{ y }`. Since the object has no `y` property you get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am i getting `undefined` after passing empty object?

Because you have used an object, so no assignment of the default value takes place.

```
         lol(              {},         {}         ); // 10, undefined
function lol( { x = 10 } = {}, { y } = { y : 10 } ) {
// resolves to
function lol( { x = 10 } = {}, { y } = {}         ) {
```

> And why am i getting default value of `10` for `y` when lol()?

Because you did not supply an object. Then the default object is taken and the destructuring takes place with the default object.

```
         lol(                                     ); // 10, undefined
function lol( { x = 10 } = {}, { y } = { y : 10 } ) {
// resolves to
function lol( { x = 10 } = {}, { y } = { y : 10 } ) {
```